# Getting conserved region in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the conserved region from `MSA` (`Multiple Sequence Alignment`) using python script.

The file look like that

```
MW581643.1.  attaaaggtttataccttcccaggtaacaaaccaaccaactttcgatctcttgtagatct

MW467482.1   attaaaggtttataccttcccaggtaacaaaccaaccaactttcgatctcttgtagatct
                                                                       
                                                                  ***** 
MW581643.1  gttctctaaacgaactttaaaatctgtgtggctgtcactcggctgcatgcttagtgcact

MW467482.1  gttctctaaacgaactttaaaatctgtgtggctgtcactcggctgcatgcttagtgcact

            *************** * ******************************************
```

I want to extract the sequence of stars (simpley to tell python if you see that stars print the above sequence)

I tried that code thankfully someone recommended but it works with one line, any help please ?

Thanks in advance

```
    import re

    seq1, stars = f.readline(), f.readline()

    conserved_blocks = re.finditer("\*+", stars)

    for block in conserved_blocks:

        if len(block.group()) >= 1:

           print(seq1[block.start(): block.end()])
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your code?

Comment: you have to use `for`-loop  or `while True` loop to repeate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run it in loop to repeate code.

I assume `seq1` always get some string (there is no empty lines for `seq1`)

```
while True:
    seq1, stars = f.readline(), f.readline()
    
    if not seq1.strip():
        break

    # ... rest ...
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help and efforts, what if my file have empty line?

Comment: if `f.readline()` gets empty line and it assings to `seq1` then `if not seq1.strip():` will exit `while True` and it will skip rest of file.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to contributors, finally my code work

```
    f=open(file, 'r')
    Seq1=[]
    Stars=[]
    while True:
       import re
       Seq1, Stars = f.readline(), f.readline()
       conserved_blocks = re.finditer("\*+", Stars)
       for block in conserved_blocks:
           if len(block.group()) >= 1:
              Alignment=list(Seq1[block.start(): block.end()])
              x=[''.join(x) for x in Alignment]
              print(x)
     if not Seq1.strip(""):
         break
```